# can't convert true into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, haml

I'm having some problem with what I think is my cache.

I'm getting this error message:

`ListsUsersController# (ActionView::Template::Error) "can't convert true into String"`

Here is the code:

```
%footer
  - cache "footer-movies-#{Time.now.hour.to_s}", expires_in: 2.days do
    .foot-movies
      %ul
        - Movie.footer.each do |movie|
          %li= link_to (image_tag movie.poster, size: "60x92"), movie_path(movie), title: movie.title
```

It's complaining about line 40, which is the line containing `.foot-movies`.

The code works most of the time, but sometimes raises this error.
I've not seen it my self in a while, but [Exceptional](http://www.getexceptional.com/) tells me that the error has been raised over 500 times the last 7 days.

I'm using:

- haml 3.1.2
- rails 3.1
- memcached 1.4.5
- dalli 1.0.5

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1190967) is the full stacktrace.

Comment: some remarks: don't do a `to_s` when using an interpolated string. don't misuse parentheses `image_tag(movie.poster, size: "60x92")`

Comment: from the stacktrace that you posted, it looks like the cache returns true instead of a string. are you using the same cache-key somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

One of the variables or methods you have doesn't have a string in it its simply 'true' and ruby wont convert that to a string. You'd have to hunt down which of these it is and make sure its passing the right value